# Synonym for "agnostic"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there another word for **agnostic** when used in reference to technology?

For example

> The keyboard is OS **agnostic** and operates on most modern operating systems.

Comment: Perhaps _independent_ would be a good synonym?

Comment: While the word independent is very good, agnostic is that standard word used in IT for such neutrality. *Neutral* itself would otherwise work.

Comment: @J.R. Would you like to post that up as an answer and I'll mark it if no one else offers a better alternative.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Wish I could mark more than one answer but if you would also like to post up Neutral as an answer I will give it an upvote.

Comment: @Puddler You can answer your own question as well, if you found a better one.

Comment: @NVZ Unfortunately I didn't find anything better than what has been suggested here, but the suggestions here were more than helpful.